# Access to XMLHttpRequest at [server] from origin [local] has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: api, cordova, cors

I'm using Cordova + Vuejs + Webpack in this project and I'm using cordova-plugin-advanced-http to do the post and get in my project then I'm getting this error on loading the function.

I've attached the related files below. Please help me with this.

This is the config.xml file that I had in my project:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.template" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <hook src="hooks/hookers.js" type="before_prepare"/>
    <hook src="hooks/beforedep.js" type="before_deploy"/>
    <name>Cordova - Framework7 - Vue - Webpack Template</name>
    <description>
        Brand new cordova project!
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png"/>
        <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
    </platform>
    <allow-navigation href="*"/></widget>
```

This is the sample file to execute the function:

```
    <template>
        <f7-page class="home">
            <f7-navbar title="WeCafe"></f7-navbar>

            <f7-block>
                <f7-segmented raised tag="p">
                    <f7-button large @click="changeType('pickup')" :class="{'button-active':pickup}" icon-f7="bag_fill" icon-size="16px">Pick Up</f7-button>
                    <f7-button large @click="changeType('dinein')" :class="{'button-active':dinein}" icon-material="local_dining" icon-size="16px">Dine In</f7-button>
                </f7-segmented>
            </f7-block>

            <f7-block>
                <f7-list>
                    <f7-list-input type="select" defaultValue="all">
                        <option value="all">All</option>
                        <option value="rate">Rating</option>
                        <option value="order">Highest Order</option>
                    </f7-list-input>
                </f7-list>
            </f7-block>

            <f7-block>
                <f7-card>
                    <f7-card-content :padding="false">
                        <f7-list medial-list>
                            <f7-list-item v-for="shop in shops" :key="shop.id">
                                <img slot="media" src="https://cdn.framework7.io/placeholder/fashion-88x88-4.jpg" width="44"/>
                                <p class="shop-details">
                                    {{shop.name}}
                                    <br>
                                    <small>
                                        <span class="rate">
                                            <f7-icon f7="star_fill" size="16px" color="orange"></f7-icon>4.7
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="sales">20 sold</span>
                                    </small>
                                </p>
                            </f7-list-item>
                        </f7-list>
                    </f7-card-content>
                </f7-card>
            </f7-block>

        </f7-page>
    </template>

    <style type="text/css" lang="scss">
    .home{
        .segmented-raised{
            .button{
                .icon{
                    top: -2px!important;
                    padding-right: 5px!important;
                }
            }
        }

        .card{
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-right: 0;

            .shop-details{
                margin: 0;

                .rate{
                    margin-right: 5px;
                }

                .sales{
                    margin-left: 5px;
                }
            }

        }
    }
</style>

<script>
    export default {
        components: {

        },
        data() {
            return {
                pickup: false,
                dinein: false,
                type: '',
                shops: []
            }
        },
        created: function() {
            const params = {
                method: 'get',
                data: {  },
                headers: { 'Authorization': 'hgQbNvPefnn9qnDwQQK03FCPGW5GQdrB8wUKo7DSeNul5fl7nUpJ2mtRjuWF' }
            };

            cordova.plugin.http.sendRequest('http://wecafe.uat.wepost.com.my/api/shops', params, function(response) {
                this.shops = response.data.shops;
            }, function(response) {
                console.log(response.error);
            });
        },
        methods: {
            changeType(type){
                if(type == 'pickup'){
                    this.pickup = true
                    this.dinein = false
                    this.type = type
                }else if(type == 'dinein'){
                    this.dinein = true
                    this.pickup = false
                }
                this.type = type
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

And this is the index.html file for my cordova project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="content-security-policy" content="default-src *; script-src &apos;self&apos; data: &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos; http://127.0.0.1:8081 http://192.168.8.193:8081; object-src &apos;self&apos; data: http://127.0.0.1:8081 http://192.168.8.193:8081; style-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; data: ; img-src *; media-src &apos;self&apos; data: http://127.0.0.1:8081 http://192.168.8.193:8081; frame-src &apos;self&apos; data: http://127.0.0.1:8081 http://192.168.8.193:8081; font-src *; connect-src &apos;self&apos; data: http://127.0.0.1:8081 http://192.168.8.193:8081">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <title>Device Router</title>

    <style>
        html {
            background: #DDD;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #222;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        html, body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        html * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #unavailable {
            display: block;
        }

        #unavailable p {
            display: none;
            font-size: 15px;
            background: #444;
            color: #FFF;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            line-height: 24px;
        }

        #status_text {
            display: block;

            background: #2196F3;
            color: #FFF;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 10px;

            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        input {
            display: block;
            background: #FFF;
            border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #222;
            width: 100%;
            height: 46px;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        button {
            display: block;
            margin-top: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 34px;
        }

        .input_wrap {
            padding: 0 10px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body><script>const localServerIp = '192.168.8.193'</script>

    <div id="unavailable">
        <p>
            It seems we can&apos;t connect to<br>127.0.0.1:8081<br>
            <script>document.write(localServerIp)</script>
            :8081<br><br>
            You can test yourself with next inputs:
        </p>

        <div id="status_text">
            Waiting for device ready...
        </div>

        <div class="input_wrap">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Server Ip:Port (like 192.168.0.2:8081)" disabled>
        </div>

        <div class="input_wrap">
            <button type="button" onclick="tryConnect()" disabled>Connect</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var deviceReadyChecker = setTimeout(startRedirectChecks, 5000);

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
            clearTimeout(deviceReadyChecker);

            if (typeof navigator.splashscreen !== "undefined" && typeof navigator.splashscreen.hide === "function")
                navigator.splashscreen.hide();

            startRedirectChecks();
        });

        function startRedirectChecks() {
            testConnection('127.0.0.1:8081', goUrl, function () {
                testConnection(localServerIp + ':8081', goUrl, ajaxErr)
            })
        }

        function tryConnect() {
            var ipTest = /^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(:[0-9]{1,6})?$/,
            ipPort = document.querySelector("input").value;

            if (ipTest.test(ipPort))
                testConnection(ipPort, goUrl, ajaxErr);
        }

        function testConnection(ipPort, callback, errCallback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
            document.querySelector("input").disabled = true;
            document.querySelector("#status_text").innerText = "Trying to connect http://" + ipPort;

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    document.querySelector("#status_text").innerText = "Connection to 'http://" + ipPort + "/' success! Redirecting...";

                    if (typeof callback === "function")
                        callback(ipPort);
                }
                else if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status !== 200) {
                    document.querySelector("button").disabled = false;
                    document.querySelector("input").disabled = false;
                    document.querySelector("#status_text").innerText = "Connection to 'http://" + ipPort + "/' failed!";

                    if (typeof errCallback === "function")
                        errCallback(ipPort);
                }
            }

            xhr.open('GET', 'http://' + ipPort + '/');
            xhr.send(null);
        }

        function goUrl(ipPort) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.href = 'http://' + ipPort + '/'
            }, 1500);
        }

        function ajaxErr(ipPort) {
            document.querySelector("#unavailable p").style.display = "block";
            console.log('Can\'t connect to http://' + ipPort + '/');
        }

    </script>


    <script src="cordova.js"></script></body></html>
```

Comment: Sharing codes as text is better way to get helped. Consider putting your code as text not image.

Comment: Ok, this is my first time posting problems in stackoverflow so I don't actually know how to do. Thanks.